# Music Self-Evaluation: Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

**[EDIT]:** As promised, here's some aggregated feedback from the team.

> While your question quality is seemingly pretty solid, what's most concerning is your low questions per day. The traffic stats and Area 51 card would indicate that you all are growing -- more users, more visits, more eyes on the site, etc. -- but it appears much of that traffic is passive and not asking the important questions. To me, that seems like your audience is being served elsewhere.
>
> In fact, it seems like your overall activity is falling off, which is troubling; you're coming around the bend to being two years in beta, but it seems you've stopped growing.
>
> Fortunately, all is not lost! You're in the middle of a new semester, and plenty of students and practitioners should be restarting their practice anew. Perhaps toss good posts onto Reddit, or into university mailing lists? Music education courses would also benefit greatly from out site, in my opinion. Some low-level promo work from the community could go quite a long way.
>
> Otherwise: stay the course. We'd like you to grow, but you're fine just the way you are right now.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: This one is for sure much kinder than the last public one! The "random questions" chosen this time are MUCH better on the whole.

Comment: Not many voting.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, everyone! I'll do my best to get your feedback to you asap! :)

Comment: Woah. I completely missed this! I didn't expect another so soon after the previous.

Answer (score 2):

[What kind of effect does practicing on difficult to play instruments have?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/what-kind-of-effect-does-practicing-on-difficult-to-play-instruments-have)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Lots of good answers on this one.

Answer (score 2):

[Grace notes in Minuet by Boccherini](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6719/grace-notes-in-minuet-by-boccherini)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 2):

[How can I reproduce the effects on this riff in Iron Maiden - Afraid to Shoot Strangers?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/how-can-i-reproduce-the-effects-on-this-riff-in-iron-maiden-afraid-to-shoot-st)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Very detailed question and answer. We clearly have some real intellectual capital in the guitar tag.

Answer (score 2):

[Sixth and Minor Seventh inversions conflicts](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6756/sixth-and-minor-seventh-inversions-conflicts)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[How to keep guitar strings from breaking so quickly?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6802/how-to-keep-guitar-strings-from-breaking-so-quickly)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[How could you make instrumental sounds come out of a computer?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6746/how-could-you-make-instrumental-sounds-come-out-of-a-computer)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I would have expected this question to have more views--although the wording of the question title is a little strange.

Answer (score 1):

[Is there any practical difference between 3/4 and 3/8 time?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/is-there-any-practical-difference-between-3-4-and-3-8-time)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[Acoustic guitar damaged by impact. How to repair?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6790/acoustic-guitar-damaged-by-impact-how-to-repair)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I avoid making unpleasant facial expressions when playing difficult chords?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6784/how-can-i-avoid-making-unpleasant-facial-expressions-when-playing-difficult-chor)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Kind of a silly question IMO.

Answer (score 0):

[how do you choose the correct stem length for notes on a beam?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6715/how-do-you-choose-the-correct-stem-length-for-notes-on-a-beam)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Important question, but the community doesn't yet have an expert on engraving, and I find the answers subpar as a result.

Comment: I definitely feel this would be a very good topic of questions if only we had knowledgeable base of users in this area.

Comment: So anyone know any experts on this topic to share this question with?